# django: allow allowed_hosts to work with debug = True also

Tags: django

I have a requirement that my django app `ALLOWED_HOSTS=["somedomain.com"]` work when `DEBUG=True`

Because it only works for `DEBUG=False`

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this.